# Git Fetch: Permission Denied

Tags: git, apache, centos7, selinux, git-fetch

I am facing "permission denied" error only on running `git fetch`. pull, push etc other commands are working fine.

I am trying this in cent-OS bash with the `apache` user.

I have tried by updating ssh keys, `git fsck & git fetch -f`.
Also I cannot find any detail about this in `.git/logs`

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Do you use a public git server or a self-hosted one? What (file/directory) permissions do you have locally?

Comment: Public git server. I have granted ownership of the repo dir to apache user.

Comment: Do you clone the repository using the dumb http protocol?

Comment: It worked when i changed the permissions of .git forlder in the repo to chmod 700

Comment: The permissions of the local or remote `.git` folder? What were the permissions before that?

Comment: the local .git folders permissions were modified when accessed by root user, i didn't note them exactly but gave it a+x and it worked.